# simple AJAX dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this ajax code for getting the current selection, so I can later call database with php `GET`. Firebug error:

> Missing ) after argument list -"success":function(data){

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        $.ajax(
            "file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(),
            "success":function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
            }
        )
    })
});
</script>
<select id="select">
<option> something </option>
<option> something2 </option>
<option> something3 </option>
</select>

<?php

//echo $_GET['selected'];

?>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: There's syntax error on your code
 $.ajax({
            url:"file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(),
            "success":function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
            }
        )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the 'url' property name before `"file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(),`:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(), //note the property name 'url'
        "success":function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    })
```

Comment: That's still syntactically invalid.

Comment: @LinusKleen -- could your comment be less helpful? Rather than just saying "Wrong!", why not exercise your fingers just a little more and type out what is wrong about it, such as "you're missing the curly braces!" Not only would it be helpful for future users who come to this question, it would be helpful for the OP because he also is missing those braces.

Comment: No need to get this excited. Consider it an exercise for the reader. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write the ajax function in this way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(),
  success: function(data) {
      $("#results").html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using the syntax you already have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        $.ajax(
            "file.php?selected=" + $(this).val(),{
               success:function(data){
                   $("#results").html(data);
            }}
        );
    });
});
```

You can indeed pass the URL as the first argument of an AJAX call. You just were missing creating a JSON object around the success callback part of the call.